# Creating a for loop within a for loop with an if statement

Tags: python

I am trying to create a for loop within a for loop, with an if statement with the following code where N and r are both columns of float numbers.

```
x     = math.floor(max(N)*2)
x_1   = np.zeros((x,1),dtype=np.int16)

for i in range (1,x):
       for j in range (1, max(N)):
           if N[i] = (i-1)/2:
               x_1[i] = max(x_1[j], r[i])
```

The error I am getting here is invalid syntax for the line:
`if N[i] = (i-1)/2:`
Specifically under the equals sign.

Comment: You need a double equal sign for comparisons ==

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've updated by code with the == signs. It appears to be working, but never converges on  an answer (just shows the hourglass that the code is running). I know my N is a numpy array, my x and x_1 are 'int', and my r is a pandas.core.series. Do I need to add anything additional to make this converge faster? Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You need a double equal sign for comparisons.

```
if N[i] == (i-1)/2:
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've updated by code with the == signs. It appears to be working, but never converges on an answer (just shows the hourglass that the code is running). I know my N is a numpy array, my x and x_1 are 'int', and my r is a pandas.core.series. Do I need to add anything additional to make this converge faster? Any help is appreciated!!